# Sequelize top level where with Op.or gives error

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am upleveling the includes to top level "where" so that I can OR it:

```
MODEL_A.findAll({
                where: {
                    [Op.Or] : [
                        {
                            '$MODEL2_DETAIL.COLNAME$' : { [Op.eq]: 5 } 
                        }, {
                            '$MODEL3_DETAIL.COLNAME$' : { [Op.eq]: 5 }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                include: [{
                            model: MODEL2
                            as: 'MODEL2_DETAIL'
                        }, {
                            model: MODEL3,
                            as: 'MODEL3_DETAIL'
                        }
                        ]
                })
```

It gives error:

"Invalid value { '$MODEL2_DETAIL.COLNAME$': { [Symbol(eq)]: 5 } }"

If I put it without the Op.Or, it works

```
MODEL_A.findAll({
                where: {
                            '$MODEL2_DETAIL.COLNAME$' : { [Op.eq]: 5 } 
            }                  
                }...
```

Above works!
Any other suggestions how I can OR on multiple models?

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

Comment: I tried similar request and it works. Are you sure this is an exact error you got for this request?

Comment: Yes. Exact error:  "Invalid value { '$MODEL2_DETAIL.COLNAME$': { [Symbol(eq)]: 6 } }"

Comment: Shouldn't `Op.Or` be `Op.or`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to be Op.or instead of Op.Or
Thank you @anatoly for noticing!